# How do I select the top 30 items in a C# checkbox control with a single button click

Tags: c#, windows, forms, checkbox

I have windows app that I am building and want to be able to click one button and select the top 30 entries in a check box control. The select all is easy. Of course I could be overlooking the simplicity here, but it is not making sense right now.

Edited; Here is what I have that works for selecting all entries.

```
        private void ckTop_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // either check all or uncheck all
        if (ckTop.Text == "Check all")
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < CLB.Items.Count; i++) CLB.SetItemChecked(i, true);
            ckTop.Text = "Uncheck all";
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < CLB.Items.Count; i++) CLB.SetItemChecked(i, false);
            ckTop.Text = "Check all";
        }
    }
```

I have tried setting the CLB.SetItemChecked(i, true); to a value of 4 to see if it would select the fourth entry, but that did not work.

Comment: What is the precise type of the "check box control"?

Comment: You need to post the code that you've already tried, and explain what went wrong with it.

Comment: The way your question currently stands, the answer is "by finding the top 30 items". However, if you want a specific answer, you'll need to give us a specific question like Archer already requested.

Comment: a WinForms `checkBox` doesn't have items. Do you mean a `CheckedListBox`?

Comment: Apologies, it is a CheckedListBox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this should do the trick for you,

```
for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++)
{
    checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(i, true);
}
```

Comment: I am now Ive changed the arrow direction, that's what happens when I look away for a moment